# selected value vue js

Tags: vue.js, select

```
<div class="form-group">
              <select v-model="selected_agent">
                <option v-for="agent in agents" v-bind:value="agent.id" v-bind:key="agent.id">{{agent.first_name}}</option>
              </select>
          </div>
```

I try to do this

```
newRout.agent_id = this.selected_agent.id;
```

but this.selected_agent undefined

Comment: `addRoutesClicked() {
                    let newRout = this.rout;
                    newRout.trade_point_id = vm.selected_point.id;
                    newRout.agent_id = this.selected_agent.id;
                    newRout.day_of_week = this.selected_day.value;
                    newRout.visit_date = this.visit_date.value;
                MainDataService.createRout(newRout)
                .then(()=>{
                    this.refreshRoutes()
                })`

Comment: i incorrectly use v-bind:value

Answer (score 0):

v-bind:value equel selected value

and correctly

```
newRout.agent_id = this.selected_agent
```

because: `v-bind:value="agent.id"`